# html lang="" instead of lang="en-us" - why?

Tags: wp-config, language

In a few installations of wordpress, the beginning of the html tag looks like

```
<html lang="en-US" ...
```

despite that in wp-config no language is specified.

```
define('WPLANG', '');
```

Hovever, in one installation the tag is

```
<html lang=" " ...
```

how would i change that to `<html lang="en-us" ...`, without changing the wp-config file

I'm talking about the front end, not the admin dashboard.

The code in header.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
```

and the HTML render looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=" " prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" class="no-js">
<head>
...
```

Comment: Are you talking about the admin pages or the front end? If the latter, look at your theme's `header.php` file (it might be called something similar) and paste the line with the opening `<html ...>` tag here.

Comment: Is there a workaround without hard coding that?

Comment: It depends on your answers to the questions I asked in the question above! Can't tell without understanding context (question 1) and seeing code (question 2).

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Are the sites without the language specified using a theme with a hard-coded language attribute? I don't see how you could get around not hard-coding it in one of `wp-config.php` or `header.php`.

Comment: I don't want to modify header.php, i want to call language_attributes() function.

So, the only solution would be to set the language in wp-config.php?

Comment: I sure think so, is there a reason not to specify it?

Comment: You neglected to say what the WPLANG is actually set to in this site. Is it blank? Empty? An empty space? Also, what plugin do you have that is inserting this Facebook information? What happens if you disable that plugin?

Comment: @Otto - it's empty.
The plugin insertin Facebook information is SEO by Yoast. When I disable the plugin, it just removes the Open Graph info

Comment: Well, okay then, in that case you need to do some more investigating as to the source of the problem. If WPLANG is empty, then the resulting lang should be "en-US". Something else must be going on to cause this to be incorrect, finding out the cause is where you should focus your efforts.

Comment: The funny thing is that i used WP Clone to clone the installation on my localhost, and in localhost, the lang tag IS en-US. So, i really don't have a clue what might be going on.

Could it be some server related setting, like .httaccess

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the `language_attributes` filter to [`language_attributes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/language_attributes) function ([source](http://queryposts.com/function/language_attributes/)).

Basically you can do this by adding something like this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('language_attributes', 'custom_lang_attr');
function custom_lang_attr() {
  return 'lang="en-US"';
}
```

Note: Keep in mind, that you're overwriting the language parameter; the original string (see `@param`) is a space-separated list of language attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sven.
Can i somehow, in a similar manner, set a language for rss feed?

Comment: @Nicholas It's probably a better idea to define `<language>` within the RSS feed. But that's a [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ;)

Comment: [New question it is then](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159104/setting-the-language-of-rss-feed) :)