# Setting the language of RSS feed

Tags: rss, language

What is the simplest / easiest way to set up the language of the rss feed.
Currently, that field in my feed xml is blank, it looks like this

```
 <language></language>
```

and i would like it to look like

```
<language>en-US</language>
```

Any help on how to easily implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the default [feed template](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.2/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php) you'll find something like this:

```
<language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>
```

As you can see the bloginfo for the feed (`bloginfo_rss()`) is called (instead of `get_bloginfo()`). You can overwrite the feed language separately via a filter in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('bloginfo_rss', 'custom_rss_lang_attr', 10, 2);
function custom_rss_lang_attr($output, $show) {
  switch( $show ) {
    case 'language':
      $output = 'en-US';
      break;
  }
  return $output;
}
```

**Update:** As @toscho pointed out it's bad practice to use a `switch` with just one case. Keep it simple and use an `if` statement:

```
add_filter('bloginfo_rss', 'custom_rss_lang_attr', 10, 2);
function custom_rss_lang_attr($output, $show) {
  if ( $show == 'language' ) {
    $output = 'en-US';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for that lonely `switch` statement?

Comment: Great reply! Thanks.
Also, is it a good idea to force higher update period and / or frequency? The default is update period == hour and update frequency == 1

Comment: @Nicholas This depends on your personal preferences and the amount of content you can provide. It probably doesn't make sense to update the feed if there is no new content.